# Problem about machine learning and dataframe

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

i found a problem about the layer of dataset for the training:

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential_4" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 7), found shape=(None, 5)
```

This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.regularizers import l2
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def carica_dataset():
dataset = pd.read_csv("dataset.csv")
return dataset

def carica_modello():
    dataset = carica_dataset()
    dataset = pd.get_dummies(dataset, columns=['Località'])
    print(dataset)
    X = dataset.drop(columns=['Prezzo'])
    y = dataset['Prezzo']

    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y)

    model = Sequential()

    model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu', input_dim=X_train.shape[1],  kernel_regularizer=l2(0.1)))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu',  kernel_regularizer=l2(0.1)))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(16, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=l2(0.1)))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(8, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=l2(0.1)))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation='linear', kernel_regularizer=l2(0.1)))
    adam = Adam()

    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=adam, metrics=['accuracy'])

    model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=100, batch_size=64)


    return model

 dataset = carica_dataset()
 model = carica_modello()
 fields = {
    'Superficie': float,
    'Numero di stanze da letto': int,
    'Numero di bagni': int,
    'Anno di costruzione': int,
    'Località': str
     }
 user_data = {}

for key,value in fields.items():
    while True:
        try:
            user_input = input(f"inserisci il valore di: {key}")
            user_data[key] = value(user_input)
            break
        except ValueError:
            print(f"inserisci un valore valido per {key}")
dataframe = pd.DataFrame([user_data])
dataframe = pd.get_dummies(dataframe, columns=['Località'])

valori = dataframe.values

prediction = model.predict(valori)[0][0]
print(f'La predizione del prezzo è: {prediction} €')
```

i tried to change the numbers of layers but i found every time the same problem, what can i do?

my dataset has 6 columns -1, that is the columns that i need to predict, so 5 columns

Comment: set input_dim to 5 then, seems you are changing the dataframe and that confuses keras.

Answer (score -1):

Try either print X_train.shape[1] right before the model definition and again right before the model fitting to verify that the number of features is consistent or just try to set input_dim=5.

Comment: 1) i tried to print X_train.shape[1] before and after the model and the output is 7 in both cases;
2)i tried to set input_dim = 5 and this is the result:


    ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential_2" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 5), found shape=(None, 7)
The expected shape and found shape have reversed from the original error

Comment: It sounds like something is wrong with dataset.csv. You should examine it in detail, as well data frame made from it. It also as if some rows have 5 and some 7 columns so it breaks when trying to run the whole tough trained on different input shapes. Also, check x_train maybe something happened when using train_test_split. Hope it helps.